# Is it possible to make a Firebug console automation?

Tags: javascript, firefox, automation, firebug

I want to automate actions in firebug JavaScript console.
ie. Is it possible to load a page from url in firefox then after the page is loaded run a js code in console? I have googled for solutions and found one:[Running_Automated_Test_Suite with FBTest](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Running_Automated_Test_Suite)

is there any other ways to do that? Which one is easier? Some ways w/ windows cmd-line/bash scripts in linux/in mac? Selenium?

Comment: i think you answered your own question

Comment: i'm just looking for other ways that i don't know. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd either use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) or [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Windows only) for this.